# Facebook GraphAPI Update Post Doesn't Work

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.5

First I created a carousel post by specifying a `message` and `child_attachments`. Then I updated it by specifying a different `message` and a different set of `child_attachments`.

But only the message got updated, not the carousel cards. I. e. `child_attachments` is ignored when requesting a post update.

How can I update the carousel cards? The [API reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/post/#updating) says "You can update the fields listed in the Publishing sections of the ..., /{page-id}/feed, ... edges." The `child_attachments` field is indeed listed in that section of the `/{page-id}/feed` edge.

I am using Graph API v2.5 and I tried this using the Graph API Explorer.

**Update**: Here is the [post](https://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=233945400270261&id=218126708518797) and below is the image of the API returning `{"success": true}` for an update that only partially happened. The image shows the `description` field to be `"4 properties"` whereas the post still shows `4 Homes`. (Also the `$` sign in the `description` is removed from `200k-500k` but the post still shows it.)
[image: the post on Facebook]

Comment: There is a current bug report for something similar (only `message` can be updated, not `link` – but in their case, they are getting an error message): https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/749078151890513 The fix for that ug is going to be pushed today – so I’d suggest you wait a day to see if that fixes your issue as well, and if not, create your own bug report.

Comment: @CBroe Thank you As of a few minutes ago it is still not working. I have updated my question with exact details of my example. I will file a bug report soon but if it looks like I am doing something wrong please let me know.

Comment: Nah, I don’t think you are doing something wrong here – if the API did not like any of the properties you are trying to update or the values you are using, then it should tell you that … instead of saying “success.” So a bug report seems totally appropriate here.